# How to package a module with my python script

Tags: python, postgresql, packaging, psycopg2

I just wrote a python script to fix some database issues and it uses the psycopg2 module. For some reason the person that needs to run it (on the server) is claiming that they can't install psycopg2 on their server machine... is there a way that I can package that module within my script such that they don't have to have psycopg2 installed? Something similar to adding a lib folder to the classpath in Java?

Thx in advance,
Andre

Comment: If the whole module's written in Python and has no extra dependencies you should just be able to put it in the same folder.

Comment: What OS is the server running? Is it the same as the OS on your machine?

Comment: The server is running CentOS, I'm on a mac.

Comment: @piro lol, that's what we ended up doing :P

Comment: great! If you contribute a patch I'll be able to use it in many of my projects! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a directory, put your script into it.

cd into that directory, then run:

```
$ easy_install -Z --prefix . psycopg2
```

That should result in a copy of the python module in the same directory.

Zip it all up and send the whole thing off.

Answer (score 0):

As to be unable to install psycopg2, I sure it relates to security policies about who can have root access on database servers.  If you can't find someone with the necessary permissions, there are two methods to skin this particular cat:

1) You could build an exe using py2exe, that way you know that all of the dependencies for your scripts are there and available.  Also this will allow to you escape dealing with any python incompatibilities.  You made no mention of your python version (2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.1?)  nor the version on the server.

2) Or you could place the psycopg2 module into its own directory (c:\mypymods) and add the path to sys.path before importing.

```
import sys
sys.path = sys.path.append("c:/mypymods")
import psycopg2
....
```